# How to remove div content with id from string in c#?

Tags: c#

```html
var result='<div class="a1">Heading 1</div><div class="a2">Heading 2</div><div class="a3">Heading 3</div>'
```

I want to remove the div and inner content with class'a2' and output should be the below

```html
var result='<div class="a1">Heading 1</div><div class="a3">Heading 3</div>'
```

Comment: A library - htmlagilitypack may help you. You can search it on google, and search how to use HtmlDocument and HtmlNode class.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I loaded all html content in c# string, Just looking a c# function like 'replace' or anything which  may helps me ?

Comment: I'd be doing it with xml me, I know it seems a bit over the top, but manipulating xml or nay markup as a string is very bad habit to get in to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regex for this

```
        string htmlWithA2 = "<div class=\"a1\">Heading 1</div><div class=\"a2\">Heading 2</div><div class=\"a3\">Heading 3</div>";
        string regex = "<div class=\"a2\">[^<>]*</div>";
        var rx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(regex);
        string htmlWithOutA2 = rx.Replace(htmlWithA2, string.Empty);
```

This suppose that you have only text and not tags in the DIV

Comment: Regex.Replace method. Don't need create Regex instance.

Answer (score 0):

If it is String in Csharp then You can use Split and Regex to get desired output.

```
string input = @"var result='<div class=""a1"">Heading 1</div><div class=""a2"">Heading 2</div><div class=""a3"">Heading 3</div>'";
            string pattern = @"<div";

            string[] pattern1 = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string i in pattern1)
            {
                if (i.StartsWith(@" class=""a2"))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if (i.EndsWith("div>") || i.EndsWith("div>'"))
                {
                    sb.Append("<div");
                }
                sb.Append(i);

            }

            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```